# Magento2.2 refused to apply css because its MIME type ('text/html') not supported

Tags: magento2.2, css

Magento2.2 apache php7 server I moved the website from a Nginx server to this apache2 server. cleared cache, the magento is in default mode still so no need to re-deploy.

However now i get an error that says

```
Refused to apply style from 'pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/css/styles-m.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.


Refused to apply style from ' pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/css/styles-l.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I already did a chmod -R 777 * in the website directory and also a chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu on the directory for the site site. so not sure what else needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: Did you manager to solve the problem?

Comment: You have deleted .htaccess file from pub/static, due to this permissions is denying, copy from fresh download magento to or from your backup and paste in above mentioned location, this issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing can happen if there is an error in your actual CSS file. This just happened to me which caused the `is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled` error. For example, I had this typo:

```
.message.global.cookie {
    background: rgba(220,20,60,0.9.5);
}
```

If you are familiar with CSS you will spot it right away. If not, it is the opacity value `0.9.5` which was invalid and should be `0.95` instead. After fixing the CSS typo the MIME error went away. The error can simply refer to an error in your CSS which isn't very clear in the error message that the browser throws.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your layout xml file under the

> app\code\yournamespace\yourmodule\view\frontend\layout

Here in the head section put your extension name before including CSS like -

```
<head>
   <css src="yournamespace_yourmodule::css/yourcssname.css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome/Firefox browser if content-type header is mixed then link will not load. This is browser strict feature.

Can you open that files in new tab of both browsers? & Please verify the content & header - **Content-Type** in Network tab by press `F12`.

If you don't see the right content or `Content-Type` then run below command:

```
rm -Rf pub/static/frontend/*

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -t Theme/name -f
```

Answer (score 0):

> follow command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```